# Get path of url in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column filled with strings in url format, i.e. starting with `https://` and ending with `/path1/path2/path3/?v=abc//123`.

I would like to select this column in a way so that I only include the path of the url (excluding the last trailing `/`character), so that the resulting string becomes `/path1/path2/path3`.

I have been looking for an answer, but have not found anything meaningful for my case so far.

Edit: The data is stored in Google BigQuery

Comment: Which dbms are you actually using? Remove the other dbms tags.

Comment: your problem can't be with sql-server + prostgresql + google-bigquery -- which is it?

Comment: We need to know because finding a substring is not standard in all SQL

Comment: Yes, that occurred to me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [NET.HOST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/net_functions#nethost) identify the host, used string manipulation to remove it entirely and then proceed with extracting the path using regex.

Consider the regex approach below:

```
with sample_data as (
  select "https://pantheon.corp.google.com/bigquery?project=project-id&ws=!1m0" as test_str
  union all select "https://pantheon.corp.google.com/path1/path2/path3/?v=abc//123" as test_str
  union all select "https://pantheon.corp.google.com/path1/path2/path3/" as test_str

),
remove_host as (
select 
test_str,
right(test_str,length(test_str)-length(concat('https://',NET.HOST(test_str)))) as trimmed,
from sample_data
)

select 
test_str,
rtrim(regexp_extract(trimmed,r'(\/[\w\-\.]+[^#?\s]+)?.*'),'/') as path
from remove_host
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I found my own solution, but it is very close to this solution. So I will verify this answer.

My solution was to also use `REGEXP_EXTRACT()` or more specifically,
`REGEXP_EXTRACT(value.string_value, r'http[s]?:\/\/?[^\/\s]+\/([^?]*)')`, although, this doesn't solve the problem as stated in the question fully.

Comment: The use of `RTRIM` is a nice touch!

Answer (score -2):

Find the location of /? and grab everything to the left of that

```
 SELECT LEFT(path_string,STR_POS(path_string,'/?')-1) AS baseURL
```

Docs are here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#left

Note, you have to make sure that all your URLS contain /? of course.  Some may not have the /

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in my case it cannot be guaranteed that the path will be followed by a query parameter `?`.

Comment: @Alien13-- I don't understand, then you just want the whole string so my query works?